How can I sniff a USB connection between a PC and a Thermal printer?
I need to develop a hardware and software solution to intercept the communications between a PC - Thermal receipt printer. The protocol between these two is USB, but i don't have any idea of where to start.
I am required to use the USB protocol, as the other ports of this printer are already in use.
I need to send the data to a server, the important part here is to capture info then ill find a way to send it.
I need to solve this problem the cheapest way possible, the max budget i can go is 50$ USD,
The hardware just needs to connect to a server to send the data, i can use a rpi/rockpi or similar.
Im open to any solution that works, here are some ways i thought on how to solve this problem:

ESP32 + RPi = using a esp32 or similar to intercept the USB signals, and log them in storage. Then the RPI would ask the esp32 for information. Why 2 devices? Because the flow of information between the PC - printer cannot stop, so if I design a super efficient c code to store the USB packets i wouldnt have to deal with SD wear and tear, bad wifi signal, etc that could affect the PC - Printer operations.

RPi Only = Using a RPi to capture the info, and then sending it when the usage of the Printer is low so as not to cause any bugs or performance issues to the actual operation of the Printer.


I havent found any concrete info on how to solve this so any help would be very appreciated, thanks in advance
Please ask me if you have any doubts

are you certain that the comm protocol is USB and not serial?

you may be on the wrong track ... maybe the question should really be how to sniff data between program XYZ and printer?

I also think this is an XY question.  I'm no expert here, but I  might attempt to solve this problem by configuring an RPi as a print server.   I can then print to it across a network and use custom drivers/filters.   https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Using_Your_Own_Filters_to_Print_with_CUPS might be a starting point.     At minimum, changing it so the devices talk to the RPi over the network will allow you to intercept traffic on a standard print port using network protocols - eg port 9100 or 631 - and still letting you connect to the printer via USB.

Also, usbmon can do packet sniffing of USB devices under Linux - but not sure how far that would get you in terms of modifying the data.

Hi guys, @jsotola yes im certain the protocol is USB, the cable is a USB A - USB B, the same one used for a home printer. The problem here is that i cannot interact with the program that is installed in the PC. To add more complications, the printer hasn't got any internal memory, the PC sends data and the printer prints the info. Thank you for your comments

@davidgo Hi david, what i thought of today was to use a RPi 4, set 1 usb port to DEVICE mode, and set another usb port to HOST mode, so as to emulate the RPi being the printer. The RPi would recieve data from the PC, and the RPi would send it to the printer wait for a response and return that response to the PC. I dont know if this is 100% possible but i will be trying, thank you for your responses

i cannot interact with the program that is installed in the PC ... you can if the printer emulates a serial port ... check the Windows device manager

Is this a homework problem perhaps? The situation seems to narrow and there seem to be too many arbitrary rules for this to be a real-world, practical problem.

Sorry guys but i cannot give more information, the problem im trying to solve is a custom solution for a client. @jsotola I cant access the PC, im only given the access to the USB cable between PC - Printer.

@music2myear Its actually a real problem, and the situation is real, if I find any workarounds I will post them here but what ive said is the actual problem i need to solve. Thanks for your comment

Guys, I found some intresting repo, https://github.com/nesto-software/USBProxy, I will be trying, Ill let you know if it works

Another option for observing USB connections is Wireshark with its built-in USBPcap integration, which i have used to successfully sniff HID traffic.

One of my personal projects deals with precisely the problem you're mentioning. The way I studied its functionality was by using a DSLogic Plus logic analyzer with sufficient sampling rate. In the case of my printer, it's 12 MHz, and respecting Shannon's sampling theorem, the sampling rate should be at least 24 MHz. However, in practice, I would recommend using at least 4 times that rate. This was purely for educational purposes to study the USB protocol, the packet types, and the ESCPOS commands.
For a final solution, I would strongly recommend using an FPGA. The downside is that you would need to master a HDL such as VHDL or Verilog.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
